# How do I change the locked screen wallpaper on iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I'm trying to use a custom wallpaper as a lock-screen wallpaper on the iPhone. Can I do that without jail breaking the phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah you sure can! Find the picture in the Photos app, press the menu button in the bottom left corner and press Use as Wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the stock wallpapers if you go to settings> wallpaper.

Another tip: You can take a screenshot by pressing the  home button and lock button at the same time. This will save a photo of what is currently on your screen to your camera roll.  which you could use as a wallpaper just like a photo